# scrollTop function returns different value when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery

scrollTop function returns different value when page is refreshed

reproduce:

1. get value of scrollTop
2. scroll down the page
3. (optional) scroll page back to top postion
4. refresh page
5. get value of scrollTop

jQuery version: 1.4

Comment: That's an ancient jQuery version. Have you considered updating to the latest?

Comment: We have huge codebase with this version. It is not easy to update libraries sometimes.

Comment: What element `scrollTop()` attached to? Maybe after the refresh there is an element that appears/dissapears before the aforementioned one - and that's why it changes

Comment: Tt is attached to window. That might be the cause because it returns the same value all the time no matter how much you scrolled. But I could not find any element which has the same height as the difference between to values.

Actually nothing appears or disappears but may be the load order of the images or something like this?

Comment: try to attach it to `body` or the very first element in your document

Comment: `may be the load order of the images or something like this` could be. When do you call `scrollTop` function? Show some simplified example.